# Paxos algorithm in the context of distributed database transaction

Tags: distributed-computing, distributed-transactions, distributed-system, paxos, consensus

I had some confusion about paxos, specifically in the context of database transactions:

In the paper "paxos made simple", it says in the second phase that the proposer needs to choose one of the values with the highest sequence number which one of the acceptors has accepted before (if no such value exists, the proposer is free to choose the original value is proposed).

Questions:

1. On one hand, I understand it does so to maintain the consensus.
   But on the other hand, I had confusion about what the value actually is - what's the point of "having to send accepters the value that has been accepted before"?
2. In the context of database transactions, what if it needs to commit a new value? Does it need to start a new instance of Paxos?
3. If the answer to the above question is "Yes", then how does accepters reset the state? (In my understanding, if it doesn't reset the state, the proposer would be forced to send one of the old values that has been accepted before rather than being free to commit whatever the new value is.)

Comment: I wrote a blog and some code to demonstrate paxos for transaction log replication at https://simbo1905.wordpress.com/2014/10/28/transaction-log-replication-with-paxos/

Answer (score 2):

There are different kinds of paxos in the "Paxos made simple" paper. One is Paxos (plain paxos, single-degree paxos, synod), another is Multi-Paxos. From an engineer's point of view, the first is distributed write-once register and the second is distributed append only log.

Answers:

1. In the context of Paxos, the actual value is the value that was successfully written to the write-once register, it happens when a majority of the acceptors accept value of the same round. In the paper it was shown that the new chosen value always will be the same as previous (if it was chosen). So to get the actual value we should initiate a new round and return the new successfully written value.

   In the context of Multi-Paxos the actual value is the latest value added to the log.
2. With Multi-Paxos we just add a new value to the log. To read the current value we read the log and return the latest version. *On the low level Multi-Paxos is an array of Paxos-registers. To write a new value we put it with a position of the current value in a free register and then we fill previous free registers with no-op. When two registers contain two different next values for the same previous value we choose the register with the lowest position in the array.*
3. It is possible and trivial with Multi-Paxos: we just start a new round of the Paxos over a free register. Although plain Paxos doesn't cover it, we can "extend" it and turn into a distributed variable instead of the dist. register. I described this idea and the proof in the ["A memo on how Paxos works"](http://rystsov.info/2015/09/16/how-paxos-works.html) post.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than answering your questions directly, I'll try explaining how one might go about implementing a database transaction with Paxos, perhaps that will help clear things up.

The first thing to notice is that there are two "values" in question here. First is the database value, the application-level data that is being modified. Second is the 'Commit'/'Abort' decision. For Paxos-based transactions, the consensus "value" is the 'Commit'/'Abort' decision.

An important point to keep in mind about database transactions with respect to Paxos consensus is that Paxos does *not* guarantee that all of the peers involved in the transaction will actually see the consensus decision. When this is needed, as it usually is with databases, it's left to the application to ensure that this happens. This means that the state stored by some peers can lag behind others and any database application built on top of Paxos will need some mechanism for handling this. This can be very complicated and is all application-specific so I'm going to ignore all that completely and focus on ensuring that a simple majority of all database replicas agree on the value of revision 2 of the database key FOO which, of course, is initially set to BAR.

The first step is to send the new value for FOO, lets say that's BAZ, and it's expected current revision, 1, along with the Paxos *Prepare* message. When the database replicas receive this message, they'll first look up their local copy of FOO and check to see if the current revision matches the expected revision included along with the *Prepare* message. If they match the database replica will bundle a "Vote Commit" flag along with it's *Promise* message sent in response to the *Prepare*. If they don't match "Vote Abort" will be sent instead (the revision check protects against the case where the value was modified since the last time the application read it. Allowing overwrites in this case could corrupt application state).

Once the transaction driver receives a quorum of *Promise* messages along with their associated "Vote Commit"/"Vote Abort" values, it must chose to propose either "Commit" or "Abort". The first step in choosing this value is to follow the Paxos requirement of checking the *Prepare* messages to see if any database replicant (the *Acceptor* in Paxos terms) has already accepted a "Commit"/"Abort" decision. If any of them has, then the transaction driver *must* choose the "Commit"/"Abort" value associated with the highest previously accepted proposal ID. If they haven't it must decide on it's own. This is done by looking at the "Vote Commit"/"Vote Abort" values bundled with the *Promise*s. If a quorum of "Vote Commmit"s are present, the transaction driver may propose "Commit", otherwise it must propose "Abort".

From that point on, it's all standard Paxos messages that get exchanged back and forth until consensus is reached on the 'Commit'/'Abort' decision. Assuming 'Commit' is chosen, the database replicants will update the value and revision associated with FOO to BAZ and 2, respectively.

Comment: still don't understand why we need to compare revisions on backup node on prepare step, could u explain in more detail

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [long blog with links to sourcecode](https://simbo1905.wordpress.com/2014/10/28/transaction-log-replication-with-paxos/) on the topic of doing transaction log replication with paxos as described in the [Paxos Made Simple](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/pubs/paxos-simple.pdf) paper. Here I  give short answers to your questions. The blog post and sourcecode shows the complete picture.

> On one hand, I understand it does so to maintain the consensus. But on
>   the other hand, I had confusion about what the value actually is -
>   what's the point of "having to send accepters the value that has been
>   accepted before"?

The value is the command the client is trying to run on the cluster. During an outage the client value transmitted to all nodes by the last leader may have only reached one node in the surviving majority. The new leader may not be that node. The new leader discovers the client value from at least one surviving node and then it transmits it to all the nodes in the surviving majority. In this manner, the new leader collaborates with the dead leader to complete any client work it may have had in progress.

> In the context of database transactions, what if it needs to commit a
>   new value? Does it need to start a new instance of Paxos?

It cannot choose any new commands from clients until it has rebuilt the history of the chosen values selected by the last leader. The blog post talks about this as a "leader takeover phase" where after a crash of the old leader the new leader is trying to bring all nodes fully up to date.

In effect whatever the last leader transmitted which got to a majority of nodes is chosen; the new leader cannot change this history. During the takeover phase it is simply synchronising nodes to get them all up to date. Only when the new leader had finished this phase is it known to be fully up to date with all chosen values can it process any new client commands (i.e. process any new work).

> If the answer to the above question is "Yes", then how does accepters
>   reset the state?

They don't. There is a gap between a value being chosen and any node learning that the value had been chosen. In the context of a database you cannot "commit" the value (apply it to the data store) until you have "learnt" the chosen value. Paxos ensures that a chosen value won't ever be undone. So don't commit the value until you learn that the value has been chosen. The blog post gives more details on this.

Answer (score 0):

This is from my experience of implementing raft and reading the ZAB paper. Which are the two prevalent incarnations of PAXOS. I haven't really gotten into simple paxos or multipaxos.

When a client sends a commit to any node in the cluster, it will redirect that commit to the leader the leader then sends the commit message to each node in the quorum, when all of the nodes confirm the commit it will commit to it's own log.